# Python Pandas Move Na or Null values to a new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know I can drop NaN rows from a DataFrame with `df.dropna()`. But what if I want to move those NaN rows to a new DataFrame?
Dataframe looks like

```
FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS, latitude, logitude, altitude
BOB, JONES, 555 Seaseme Street, 38.00,-91.00,0.0
JOHN, GREEN, 111 Maple Street, 34.00,-75.00,0.0
TOM, SMITH, 100 A Street, 20.00,-80.00,0.0
BETTY, CROCKER, 5 Elm Street, NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I know I can group and move to a new DataFrame like this

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.FNAME)
df1 = grouped.get_group("BOB")
```

and it will give me a new DataFrame with `FNAME` of BOB but when I try

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.altitude)
df1 = grouped.get_group("NaN")
```

I get a `KeyError: 'NaN'`. So how can I group by Nan or Null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're satisfied that all `'Nan'` values in a column are to be grouped together, what you can do is use `DataFrame.fillna()` to convert the `'Nan'` into something else, to be grouped.

```
df.fillna(value={'altitude':'null_altitudes'}
```

This fills every null in the `altitude` column with the string `'null_altitudes'`. If you do a groupby now, all `'null_altitudes'` will be together. You can fill multiple columns at once using multiple key value pairs:  `values = {'col_1':'val_1', 'col_2':'val_2', etc}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) on rows:

```
# to get rows with NA in a new df
df1 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```